# Splitting Declaration and Assignment = Good Practice?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment, declaration

Being an avid user of NetBeans, I keep getting suggestions to split my variable declarations and assignments when I introduce a new variable. As a super quick example off the top of my head, let's take this Java line:

```
String someInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "- Enter something: ");
```

versus:

```
String someInput;
someInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "- Enter something: ");
```

NetBeans seems to prefer the latter (I wouldn't know about other IDEs, though). While it clearly works both ways, which would be considered 'good practice', if at all?  Or s it purely a matter of personal preference?

(Obviously splitting the two means an extra line that you could've just combined into one, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: It puzzles me that anyone would prefer the latter over the former.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you have some funny code style thing going on in NetBeans!

Comment: The first option is an "economic" way to initialize the object. (I think) The second one is just a bit cleaner, because it allows to group the variable declaration from the assignment. I think that from a purely aesthetic point of view, the second one is preferible, but the first one is more desirable in terms of simplicity

Comment: I suggest you do what you find is the simplest and clearest.  For me that is the first case.

Comment: I'm wondering why you see this hint in the first place. I haven't ever seen an hint like this in NetBeans 7.0.1 and I looked through the options and I didn't see one like this either.

Comment: @Stanley: Not sure, but it happens quite often to me (though not always). I'm using 7.2.1.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with Android Studio - why anyone would want to add useless extra lines of code is beyond me.

Comment: Pretty sure netbeans usually only offers this when the line is highlighted, and it isn't really a 'problem'. It is a optional shortcut, just like the 'invert if statement' 'warning'.

Comment: Android studio was doing the same. I've turned the notification off.

Comment: It could be bug in NetBeans..!!

Comment: DaboRoss has this right. Netbeans doesn't "prefer" the lines to be split; it's just _offerring_ to split them if you find it useful, as a shortcut. Personally I sometimes split them when I want to set a default value on a variable, overridden in a conditional if applicable.

Comment: No clue why this would be marked "not constructive": simple, precise question about an indicator in a popular IDE.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's no reason to split the declaration and the assignment if you're just going to have them on consecutive lines.  I'd only split them if the assignment were conditional, or if it needed to go in a separate code block (like a try/catch, or if the assignment goes in a constructor, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that about clears it up. Better to stick to what makes sense to you than to the IDE!

Answer (score 19):

A common pattern that traces back to early statically typed programming is to declare all the variables you need at the top of the block they need to be scoped in, and then assign to those values subsequently.

With that said, as long as you're able to clearly communicate the intent of your code to the people you work on it with, or yourself in a year's time, it shouldn't really matter.

> Let us change our traditional attitude to the construction of programs: Instead of imagining that our
>   main task is to instruct a computer what to do, let us
>   concentrate rather on explaining to human beings what
>   we want a computer to do. -- Donald Knuth

Comment: +1 `declare; declare; declare; assign; assign; assign;` is probably the style NetBeans is trying to coerce, rather than `declare; assign; declare; assign; declare; assign;`.

Answer (score 16):

This was an option added to NetBeans somewhere between 7.0 and 7.3. If you don't like this hint it can be changed by unchecking:
Tools > Options > Editor > Hints > Suggestions > Split Declaration

[image: Screenshot of NetBeans > Prefs > Hints > Suggestions > Split Declaration]

Comment: For IntelliJ IDEA it's at File - Settings - Editor - Intentions - Java - Declaration - Split Declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans suggests this as it can speed up coding, for example consider this assignment

```
final String myString = "somevalue"
```

You then decide that actually the value depends on some `boolean`

```
final String myString;
if(something) {
    myString = "somevalue"
} else {
    myString = "someothervalue"
}
```

To convert one from to the other you can use the code hint to spilt declaration and assignment and the `if...else` template to generate the code in very few steps.

In general if you are assigning unconditionally then there is not reason to split declaration and assignment.

Comment: I don't think splitting declaration from assignment to preempt the use of such a case (if/else, try/catch, etc.) is worth it, when you consider it requires the rewriting of the variable's name.

Comment: "Let's make all code longer and needlessly more complex, so we can shave an negligible amount of time off an already fast task in the off chance it is one day necessary." Yeah. No.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov the code is different. One is a direct assignment and one is a conditional assignment. I really don't see how your comment fits in.

Comment: My point is that the NetBeans reasoning is dumb. They discourage direct initialization and prefer this pointless 2 line approach, on the off-chance that it make it easier to one day make the assignment conditional.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov they do not. Your comment is entirely false. Sorry.

Comment: Is it? The default setting is to throw a warning on `final String myString = "somevalue"`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov it's not a "warning", it's a hint. The same type of hint is shown, for example, when you place the cursor on a `class` declaration suggesting that you `extend` the `class`. You could argue that NetBeans is pushing inheritance over composition. Or you could say that NetBeans is trying to tell you everything you can do with a line of code with a single shortcut to _help_ developers **not** make design decisions for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129329/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-boris-the-spider).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a big deal. Pick a style you like, and stick to it throughout (if you're in a team, it helps if everyone is laying out their code similarly).

I personally prefer to initialize my variables right at the point of declaration. For that reason, I would prefer the former over the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Code Complete, which is well regarded by most of the programming community, suggests in its page 241 that as a matter of defensive programming you can either initialize each variable as it's declared (your first option) or initialize it close to where it is first used (your second option).

Nevertheless, the book suggests that the second option is better because if you use the first option, your variable may have changed between its declaration and its usage.

In your case, the difference between declaration and usage in the second case is a single line. Hence, the book's concerns do not apply. Nevertheless, its concerns are legitimate and this may be the reason Netbeans designers included this tip (even though they overused it).

Comment: You appear to be misapplying the book's advice. The page you're referencing states that "Some languages, including Visual Basic, don't support initializing variables as they're declared", but Java is not one of those languages, and so this does not apply. The book goes on to state "Ideally, declare _and_ define each variable close to where it's first used ... In languages that support it, such as C++ and Java, variables should be declared and defined close to where they are first used." It's not an either-or proposition with Java.